# from csv to scatter plot with HighCharts

Tags: csv, highcharts, time-series, timestamp, scatter-plot

I have csv data in a file like this which I want to visualize for myself with HighCharts. (HC 9.1.2) (I have a script to produce that csv file, so I can alter the format like adding "" around values etc.)

```
timeStamp, comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4, comp5, comp6, comp7 
2021-06-01T07:25,1.2956255070603753,5.621251073948186,nan,nan,0.5684268562524918,nan,1.0481975872029958
2021-06-01T08:25,1.8961084548957827,4.829703548214566,nan,nan,1.0555524189214427,nan,0.9991951306381098
2021-06-01T09:25,2.1008266771137323,5.5017113040150765,nan,nan,1.0486311423600163,nan,1.0431028886757223
2021-06-01T10:25,2.2899543465080057,5.244678688485554,nan,nan,1.0471302775594917,nan,1.082224140790202
2021-06-01T11:25,2.426462445619136,3.848390572693991,nan,nan,1.0686299640193513,nan,1.129274103129971
```

I'm able to plot data as normal line plot, but problem is that date stamps are not correct in produced Chart.
Second is that time interval is not constant. (Varying between 1h, 3h, 6h and 12h.) Therefore it must be a scatter plot.

Question is how to generate a scatter plot from a dataset above. First column is a date-time-stamp and then next columns are values from different parameters. (Typical environmental data)

Currently I have tried various versions of following approach:

First reading data in:

```
        var jqxhr = $.get(cstatfile, function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                a.push(items[0]);
                b.push(parseFloat(items[1]));
                c.push(parseFloat(items[2]));
                d.push(parseFloat(items[3]));
                e.push(parseFloat(items[4]));
                f.push(parseFloat(items[5]));
                g.push(parseFloat(items[6]));
                h.push(parseFloat(items[7]));
                i.push(parseFloat(items[8]));
            })
```

then trying to say which columns are what data. But not found correct way to say that Column a is  date-time-stamp for x-axis.

```
       var options = {

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    borderWidth: 3

                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Environmental dataset'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Last 30 days'
                    },
                    type: "datetime",
                },
                yAxis:  [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'component values',
                    }
                }],
                tooltip: {
                        shared: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                        line: {
                                marker: {
                                        enabled: false
                                        }
                                },
                        area: {
                                marker: {
                                        enabled: false
                                        }
                                },

                        series: {
                        }
                },
                series: [{
                        xAxis: 0,
                        name: 'timestamp',
                        data: a,
                        },{
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp1',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: b,
                        color: '#00C853',
                        lineWidth: 1
                        },
                        {
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp2',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: c,
                        color: '#40C4FF',
                        lineWidth: 1
                        },
                        {
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp3',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: d,
                        color: '#A1887F',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                        {
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp4',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: e,
                        color: '#FF3D00',
                        lineWidth: 1
                        },
                        {
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp5',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: f,
                        color: '#FF0000',
                        lineWidth: 1
                        }, {
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp6',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: g,
                        color: '#D500F9',
                        lineWidth: 1
                        }, {
                        yAxis: 0,
                        name: 'comp7',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: h,
                        color: '#0060ff',
                        lineWidth: 1
                        }]
        };
```

Tried to find an example how to do this without success. I've found some xy-scatterplot examples but couldn't fit the approach to my dataset. Then found examples where x-axis were time, but didn't manage to apply that to my dataset. So annoying not to find out the answer.

Any hints?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem and here's what I achieved: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfwtxay1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
  events: {
   load: function() {
    var chart = this;
    chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
     series.update({
      type: 'scatter'
     })
    })
   }
  }
 },
 data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
  complete: function(options) {
   console.log(options)
  }
 }
});
```

Basically, you can update all series in the load function to make them scatter series. Moreover using the complete function in the data section allows you to modify the data before parsing it to the chart.

Regarding timestamps, they depend on the data, but you can modify them using such properties as tickInterval.